# Streamwriter logs getting overwritten

Tags: c#, streamwriter

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(logpath))
{                                       
    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
    streamWriter.WriteLine("" + rst.number + "" + " , " + "Event alert details inserted successfully!");  
}
```

I'm running this code inside a foreach loop. But the logs are getting overwritten, I need to append the logs one below the other. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the for loop inside the `using` like this.

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(logpath))
{
    //for loop here
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        streamWriter.WriteLine("" + rst.number + "" + " , " + "Event alert details inserted successfully!");
    }
}
```

Problem in your code is you are initializing the `streamWriter` for every iteration of for loop. You have to create only one instance of `streamWriter`.

Use `StreamWriter(logpath, true)` to override the file.

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the file, use this [Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_).

Change:

```
new StreamWriter(logpath)
```

To:

```
new StreamWriter(logpath, true)
```

Comment: Though I agree with the other poster, you should avoid opening/closing the file in rapid succession.  Leave it open if possible until you are done writing to it...